# Rewriting IOS application

Tags: ios, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting, autolayout, ios-universal-app

I Have an old application in 2 different projects , for iPhone & iPad, historic reason.
These application have developed since ios5. 
I want to unify these 2 application and i have a dilemma.

To Create a new universal project using ARC & Storyboard & auto-layout OR continue with one of the platforms for example iPad and insert the iPhone logic there.
(Each way will cause a lot of work)

I'm not looking for the quickest way, rather i'm looking for the best way. 
I don't know if moving to ARC & Storyboard & auto-layout will worth it (Considering the fact that the code is already written)?

The only benefit i can think about is when apple will release iPhone 6 the adaptation will be simpler (OR NOT...)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to update to the universal project with ARC etc. It will be much more future proof. Also updating to use iOS7 will allow you to use the newer framework changes.

There are rumours that the new iPhone will have a bigger display / more display options. So you will want to make the most of the auto-layout functionality